# К сумме чекбоксов нужно дополнительно умножить другие чекбоксы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код. Он считает все чекбоксы таблицы и суммируется, выводя сразу результат. Но есть ещё дополнительные чекбоксы, которые должны умножаться. К примеру +20% к общей стоимости. Помогите реализовать. Если есть возможность сделать всё это на javascript, то буду благодарен.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#price").click(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('#price :checked').each(function() {
      sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('.sum').text(sum);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table pricing-table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;ЛТ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;СТ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;ТТ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;ПТ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;САУ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="price">
      <tr class="header">
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="48"><span> ЛТ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+48 руб.</span></label></td>
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="48"><span> СТ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+48 руб.</span></label></td>
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="48"><span> ТТ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+48 руб.</span></label></td>
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="48"><span> ПТ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+48 руб.</span></label></td>
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="64"><span> САУ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+64 руб.</span></label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="form-group required">
  <label class="control-label">Настройки заказа</label>
  <label class="label">
<input name="check1" value="25" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <span> Срочный заказ</span> <span class="price red"> +25%</span>
</label>
  <label class="label">
<input name="check2" value="10" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <span> Аккаунт на EU</span> <span class="price red"> +10%</span>
</label>
  <label class="label">
<input name="check3" value="5" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <span> Приложить интересные реплеи</span> <span class="price red"> +5%</span>
</label>
  <label class="label">
<input name="check4" value="25" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <span> Аккаунт свободен только ночью</span> <span class="price red"> +25%</span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="width: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
  <div>Стоимость:</div>
  <div><span class="sum">0</span> руб.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взять две переменные, в одной хранить текущую сумму, в другой - множитель. При любом иземенении чекбоксов, обновить нужную переменную, перемножить их и показать результат.

```js
var sum = 0;
var multiplier = 0;

$('#price').on("change", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var sign = $(this).prop("checked") ? 1 : -1;
  sum += sign * $(this).val();
  
  updateTotal();
});

$(".form-group").on("change", ".checkbox", function() {
  var sign = $(this).prop("checked") ? 1 : -1;
  multiplier += sign * $(this).val();
  
  updateTotal();
});

function updateTotal() {
  $(".sum").text( sum * ( 100 + multiplier ) / 100 );
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table pricing-table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;ЛТ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;СТ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;ТТ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;ПТ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;САУ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="price">
      <tr class="header">
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="48"><span> ЛТ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+48 руб.</span></label></td>
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="48"><span> СТ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+48 руб.</span></label></td>
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="48"><span> ТТ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+48 руб.</span></label></td>
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="48"><span> ПТ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+48 руб.</span></label></td>
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="64"><span> САУ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+64 руб.</span></label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="form-group required">
  <label class="control-label">Настройки заказа</label>
  <label class="label">
<input name="check1" value="25" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <span> Срочный заказ</span> <span class="price red"> +25%</span>
</label>
  <label class="label">
<input name="check2" value="10" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <span> Аккаунт на EU</span> <span class="price red"> +10%</span>
</label>
  <label class="label">
<input name="check3" value="5" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <span> Приложить интересные реплеи</span> <span class="price red"> +5%</span>
</label>
  <label class="label">
<input name="check4" value="25" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <span> Аккаунт свободен только ночью</span> <span class="price red"> +25%</span>
</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="width: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
  <div>Стоимость:</div>
  <div><span class="sum">0</span> руб.</div>
</div>
```

При желании, это можно еще сократить, и вместо переменных использовать свойства объекта:

```js
var total = {
  add: 0,
  mul: 0,
};

$('#price, .form-group').on("change", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var type = $(this).hasClass("checkbox") ? "mul" : "add";
  // Разметку не стал трогать. Можно было прямо там указать, data-type="mul или add"
  // И вместо такой проверки, сразу взять type = $(this).data("type");
  var sign = $(this).prop("checked") ? 1 : -1;
  
  total[type] += sign * $(this).val();
  updateTotal();
});

function updateTotal() {
  $(".sum").text( total.add * (100 + total.mul) / 100 );
}
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table pricing-table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;ЛТ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;СТ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;ТТ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;ПТ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
        <th class="title">
          <div class="task"><span class="name">Задачи </span><span class="class">&laquo;САУ&raquo;</span></div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="price">
      <tr class="header">
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="48"><span> ЛТ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+48 руб.</span></label></td>
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="48"><span> СТ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+48 руб.</span></label></td>
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="48"><span> ТТ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+48 руб.</span></label></td>
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="48"><span> ПТ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+48 руб.</span></label></td>
        <td class="line"><label class="task"> <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" value="64"><span> САУ-1</span></span> <span class="price">+64 руб.</span></label></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="form-group required">
  <label class="control-label">Настройки заказа</label>
  <label class="label">
    <input name="check1" value="25" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <span> Срочный заказ</span> <span class="price red"> +25%</span>
    </label>
  <label class="label">
    <input name="check2" value="10" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <span> Аккаунт на EU</span> <span class="price red"> +10%</span>
    </label>
  <label class="label">
    <input name="check3" value="5" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <span> Приложить интересные реплеи</span> <span class="price red"> +5%</span>
    </label>
  <label class="label">
    <input name="check4" value="25" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> <span> Аккаунт свободен только ночью</span> <span class="price red"> +25%</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="width: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
  <div>Стоимость:</div>
  <div><span class="sum">0</span> руб.</div>
</div>
```

Вместо класса "checkbox", `$(this).hasClass("checkbox")` хорошо бы придумать что-нибудь более оригинальное. Потому что в таком виде потом можно забыть про эту проверку, и суммирующим чекбоксам дать такие же классы.

P.s. `val()` возвращает строку, а не число. Вообще говоря, если откуда-то ожидается число, а прилетает строка, важно как можно раньше её превратить в число `Number( $(this).val() )`, но умножение меняет тип автоматически.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое! Очень помог. Если не сложно, то можешь ещё подсказать, как лучше сделать округление итогового числа?

Comment: @TheSteelFury `$(".sum").text( Math.round( total.add * (100 + total.mul) / 100 ) );` Хотя, если выражение такое длинное, появляется смысл вынести её в отдельную переменную)

Comment: Привет. Подскажи свои контактные данные.